# How can i use get texture map of a reconstruction mesh made by a 3d morphable model ? I have .obj as reconstructed mesh

Tags: computer-vision

I have used a "Accurate 3D Face Reconstruction with Weakly-Supervised Learning:
From Single Image to Image Set" in order to create a 3d morphable model out of an image . now I have got an .obj file consisting of reconstructed 3dmm. now I want to use predefined UV coordinates for each vertex of the 3D face mesh S and build a mapping f between
the UV coordinates and image pixels by reprojecting S onto
the image plane using standard rasterization
pipeline.Finally, I want to extract the texture of S from I
using the mapping f .
[this is what I want to do](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5icNn.png)]

[this is my .obj file opened in meshlab](https://i.stack.imgur.com/v978V.png)

I am new to this and I have no clue what to do.